# boolean operation between booleans and non-boolean values

Tags: python

Why this boolean operation produces a `bool`:

```py
False and "False" => False
```

whereas this one produces a `str`?

```py
False or "Value" => "Value"
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

False and "anything" will always result in a boolean False.

When you do False or "anything", the "anything" is considered as boolean True as long as it is not False or equivalent to False (like 0, 0.0, etc), and since 'False or True' is equal to true, it returns True or in your case, the string "anything" equivalent  to True.

Comment: This doesn't answer why the _boolean_ operation `or` returns a _non-boolean_ value. The correct answer is that `and` returns the _first non-truthy_ operand (or the last operand if they are all truthy), while `or` returns the _last truthy operand_ (or the last operand if they are all falsy)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi has a nice addition. But the last statement should be updated. Specifically: or returns the **first** truthy operand